# Determining which WKWebView has user interaction

Tags: swift, swiftui, wkwebview

I've got a couple of WKWebView's side-by-side on the screen.
They are in a struct conforming to UIViewRepresentable in order to use them with SwiftUI.

How can I determining which one the user is interacting with? In order to indicate visually which WebView is being used, with a red border for instance.

I know you can create a 'Coordinator' class which conforms to WKNavigationDelegate & UIScrollViewDelegate to respond to changes, but many of those changes can be performed by the site itself (scrolling, loading etc), and don't necessarily correspond to user interaction.

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        if let url = URL(string: url) {
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) { }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you can have separate delegates (WKUIDelegate and WKNavigationDelegate), and so when user performs some actions, only one delegate will receive the event, and you will know which one.

Comment: Additionally you can inject something into a loaded page which will help you identify it. This is very application specific, so has to be based on your context. But as example: if it's a react web app mostly communicating by js messages, you could inject your own listener to each WKWebView, which will report back to you when some js message happens, and since you already have separate delegates, you will know which one was active